# When International characters are written to HttpServletResponse in java using PrintWriter, it is displayed as ä½ å¥½

Tags: java, cjk, printwriter

When we write a chinese content which is got as response from a REST call to HttpServletResponse using PrintWriter as below, then, the issue occurs. In the servlet when we use the below code, it gets downloaded as CSV. The downloaded CSV has ä½ å¥½.
Sample code which is used.

```
// Sample Chinese content got as response from REST call
String content ="你好";
response.setContentType("text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Name.csv");

PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(content);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Could someone help in providing a way to print these characters as such in the csv file.

Comment: First, make sure the compiler is using an encoding that matches the encoding used to save your source file;  if you saved your source as UTF-8, the compiler needs to be treating the file as a UTF-8 file.  Second, remember to set the response’s encoding;  if you don’t set it, [getWriter() uses ISO 8859-1 by default](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter--).

Comment: my output is a file and in the response, i've given "UTF-8" in content type and if i set characer encoding as UTF-8 also it's not working... the content which i'm writing to the response is got from a REST call.

Comment: When you say “The downloaded CSV has ä½ å¥½”, how did you determine that?  How are you viewing the downloaded file?  Notepad assumes a file uses a one-byte Windows encoding, like windows-1252, unless the first character in the file is a Byte Order Mark (`\ufeff`).

Comment: I'm viewing the file using Excel in my windows system.. Basically in my application there is a facility where the content displayed in the UI can be downloaded to the system of the end user. So when the user downloads a Chinese or any other international content, it is displayed differently. So i need to make sure that the content written to the file matches the content displayed in UI.

Comment: Does `String content ="\ufeff你好";` produce different results?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this problem is the specification of Excel and Java. Excel expects the CSV files are encoded in UTF-8 with BOM, while Java writes UTF-8 without BOM.

As @VGR said in the comment, you have to add BOM (`\ufeff`) at the top of the CSV file like this:

```java
response.setContentType("text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Name.csv");
response.getWriter().print("\ufeff");
response.getWriter().print("你好\n");
response.getWriter().print("再见\n");
```